# Fix black rectangle for HTML video element

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm implementing WebRTC video chat. I want to implement the following case:

By default video element has background-image via css and if there are no video input then user see his (or interlocutor's) avatar:

No video expected result:
[image: No video expected result]

No video actual result:
[image: No video actual result]

As you can see from the screenshots I have black rectangles above my fancy backgrounds. I want to make this ugly black rectangle transparent and keep my video's backgrounds visible.

Actually it will be awesome to resolve the problem without introducing any additional markup.

Appreciate your help =)

Update:

"No video" means that user/users don't have web cams and stream has only audio track.

Comment: where does the rectangle come from? Simple remove it. Black rectangles dont appear out of nowhere :)

Comment: This black rectangle comes from <video> html element. And I could't remove it because in this case I'll remove the background and I need it. If I set "src" attribute of the video element to empty string, then it stops broadcasting audio(but cleans the black rectangle). So, I need something like <video noVideoImage="image.jpg"></video>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bingo!

Reading [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) in depth gave some results =) It was as easy:

```
<video poster="image.jpg">
```

One simple attribute made me happy

Comment: I guess you could also use `video {background-color: transparent}`.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Alpha transparency](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video) in Chrome video or `waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing`.

```
function onaddstream(event) {
    remote_video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    // remote_video.mozSrcObject  = event.stream;

    waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing();
}

function waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing()
{
    if (!(remote_video.readyState <= HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA 
        || remote_video.paused || remote_video.currentTime <= 0)) 
    {
        // remote stream started flowing!
    } 
    else setTimeout(waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing, 50);
}
```

Comment: Good try...but first, alpha transparency is supported only by Chrome Canary with special flag set(I couldn't force all my users to install this browser version), second - I'm already checking if the video starts flowing:   
if (videoTracks.length === 0) {   
    /* Hide ugly black rectangels */    
}

Comment: FWIW alpha transparency is now supported in Chrome Stable (despite what the demo says!)