# Change background-color of html5 video element

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, html5-video

I've got the following website:
beta.leifsigersen.com

There's a movie on the front page which sometimes takes a little while to load (sometimes less than a second, sometimes a few seconds). Before the movie is loaded there's black background/borders. How can I change the color of this?

I've tried to use CSS of the video-element, but without any luck.

Comment: When using HTML5 video tag, follow this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726720/fix-black-rectangle-for-html-video-element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.pk_video {
     background-color: red !important; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: It looks like the site doesn't have a video element anymore. So which element was it that you recommended putting background-color on? Was .pk_video the video tag?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the background color to the html code itself. For example:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color: #fff;" src=""></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

So i had this annoying white bar, I got rid of it using. I applied it the the containing div.

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Alternatively use

```
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think you meant rgba(0,0,0,0); ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used overlay content like so: Ionic/Angular

*.html*

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="auto" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
  <source [src]="video" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div class="overlay-content"></div>
```

.scss

```
 video {
     object-fit: cover;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 60vh;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0.5;
     -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
     -o-filter: blur(5px);
     -ms-filter: blur(5px);
     filter: blur(5px);
 }

 .overlay-content {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: rgba(6, 56, 82, 0.5);
     width: 100vw;
     height: 60vh;
 }
```