# Remove black load flash on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html5-video

I have been creating a website for an online game that I play. In the header I have a HTML5 video that plays very briefly (1second). In Internet Explorer there is no issue, however in Chrome as the video is loading there is a very brief flash of black screen. Is there any way that I can remove this flash, or, failing that, make it white to match the background? You can see what I mean here http://testingfortagpro.meximas.com/ . If you try it in IE and the Chrome you will see the difference in how the video loads. Alternatively is there any better way of implementing this? I have tried using a animated GIF however quality is significantly reduced.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974902/change-background-color-of-html5-video-element

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Poster section of this [blog post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-with-html5-video) indicates the following:

> "If you do not specify a poster image the browser may just display a
>   black box filling the dimensions of the  element."

So you can't seem to fix this by simply adding a background-color of white to the `video` element... but you can add a simple white poster image like so:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240/ffffff/fff" >
  <source src="http://testingfortagpro.meximas.com/movie2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I've uploaded the changes but it still seems to be how it was before :/

Comment: Did you try refreshing your browser cache? It worked perfectly for me in chrome in sample code.

Comment: It works fine for the first load but then if you refresh the page, or click on the other links the black box is back.

Comment: I think the black box occurs as the video is unloading. If it is that much of a deal-breaker you could try to hide the video on the page's beforeunload event.

Comment: On closer inspection I think you're right. I think this solution would work but I don't know how to go about doing it, any tips? Thanks for the help so far too.

Comment: Since you are are already using jQuery in your page, try $(window).on('beforeunload', function() { $("video").hide(); });

Comment: @TimHayes.  Very smart.

Answer (score 6):

You can use transparent gif poster:

```
poster="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

But that wasn't enough to eliminate blinking in Firefox. I ended up by hiding the video until it's playing:

```
<video autoplay style="visibility:hidden;" onplay="var s=this;setTimeout(function(){s.style.visibility='visible';},100);">
```

Adjust the timeout as you see fit. When not using autoplay, I had to increase it up to 400 ms.

Comment: This doesn't work. It flashes black and then it hides the video for the amount of time specified making it counter-productive.

Comment: @Darryl: what browser and OS are you using? You can try to remove autoplay and start the video manually.

Comment: It was happening for me on Firefox for Mac. The video I have is supposed to play on page load. That's what my client wants.

Comment: Why transparent gif and not transparent png? I realise this is an old answer but performance wise wouldnt a png be better?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by hiding the video element using CSS display:none until the video element  signalled it had finished loading via its onLoadedData event, and in response to that event I set display:block.

That got rid of the black flash.

Answer (score 1):

Putting in a poster attribute in the video tag did not stop the black box from flashing when the user refreshes the page however I used the hide function on the 'beforeunload' event and now the black flash is gone.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   $("video").hide();
});
```

Comment: Try pausing the videos. It does not hide them, just pauses. Looks smoother. Helped for me:
`$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
$("video").each( function() {
  $(this).get(0).pause();
});
});`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same blinking problem in Firefox, even with a poster attribute set. I fixed this by adding a background-image to the video tag that corresponded to the first frame of my video.

Comment: I tried that, but I continue to get the black blinky screen.

Answer (score 0):

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { $("video").hide(); });

This will hide the video element just before the window unloads and loads the next document.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the flashing black box by adding style="background-color:white;" to the video element.