# Black rectangle behind <video> element

Tags: html, css, webrtc, html5-video

I'm using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and displaying the local media with a `<video>` element. It works fine, except on my iPhone I see a black rectangle behind the video. How can I hide/remove the black rectangle?

Some things I've tried:

- Adjusting size of the video element
- `background: transparent` and `background-color: transparent`
- `overflow: hidden`

But none worked. My iPhone is running iOS 15.0.2, but it was happening on iOS 14 as well.

[image: black rectangle ios]

Full source:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
            try {
                const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
                localVideo.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
            } catch {
                alert('Please allow camera and microphone access.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <video autoplay playsinline muted id="localVideo" width=150></video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726720/fix-black-rectangle-for-html-video-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a known regression in iOS 15.0 which is fixed in 15.1:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229792

Comment: The workaround is to put the <video> element in a <div id="videoContainer">, with this CSS:
#videoContainer::before { content: 'a'; color: transparent; margin-left: -1.0em; }